# Binary search inside a buffer

Tags: java, file, search, binary, buffer

So I have implemented a working program which searches a file using the binary search method:

```
public int BSearch(int x1, int x2) throws IOException {
    int current_key;

    middle=(x1+x2)/2;
    if(x1>x2) {
        middle=-1;  //middle==-1 is condition of 'key not found'
        return middle;
    }
    MyFile.seek(middle*4);
    current_key=MyFile.readInt();
    da++;
    if(current_key==key) {
        return middle;
    }
    else if(key<current_key) {
        x2=middle-1;
        return BSearch(x1,x2);
    }
    else {
        x1=middle+1;
        return BSearch(x1,x2);
    }
}
```

Now I want to transform it so it reads the file piece-by-piece (say 1KB each time) into a buffer, and then binary search that buffer. If key is not found in that buffer I read further the file and so on. I want to clarify though that the buffer is a handmade buffer like this (correct me):

```
 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
 MyFile.read(buf);
 ByteArrayInputStream bis= new ByteArrayInputStream(buf1);
 DataInputStream ois= new DataInputStream(bis);
 current_key=ois.readInt();
```

A big problem (among others) is I don't know how I'll read from a certain position of the buffer

Comment: And why can't you just use the whole file?

Comment: The idea is that I want to use small buffers so I can handle large files (like 5 GB) the same way. Of course I won't be able to read 5GB into the main memory.

Comment: I don't think the whole file needs to be loaded to RAM. You can simply use `seek` and read the relevant bytes. The `seek` function accepts a `long`, which can address up to 8 exabytes that should be enough.

Comment: I think what you're saying is the same thing as what I've done till now, or I just can't get you:P. The reason I want to do this is to skip accessing the disc and work more with the memory, which is faster. I just don't know how to search the buffer.

Comment: What about `Arrays.binarySearch(...)`?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Also, algorithmically it's faster to search entire file at once, because when your chunks are small, your O(log n) becomes O(n).

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I managed to do it by copying the buffer to a new int[] array element-by-element. I want to believe it is still faster than accessing the disc every time I want to load a buffer.